# Equivalent of `grep -o` for findstr command in Windows

Tags: regex, batch-file, grep, findstr

In Unix, the command `grep -o` prints out only the matched string. This is very helpful when you are searching for a pattern using regular expression and only interested in what matched exactly and not the entire line.

However, I'm not able to find something similar for the Windows command `findstr`. Is there any substitute for printing only matched string in windows?

For example:

```
grep -o "10\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+" myfile.txt
```

The above command prints only the IP address in `myfile.txt` of the form `10.*.*.*` but not the entire lines which contain such IP adresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell:

```
select-string '10\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' myfile.txt | foreach-object {
   $_.Matches[0].Groups[0].Value
}
```

Comment: Hey Bill. Thanks for your answer. But the machine which I will be using my script does not have PowerShell. I'm new to batch file scripting and I did not get what you did there and hence I was not able to come up with a similar script for a Windows batch file. Could you help me with that?

Comment: What OS is the computer? PowerShell is baked in on Windows 7/Server 2008 R2 and newer. Also you can get a Win32 version of grep from [http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanks for the info. The computers I want to run the script on are running Windows XP (yes you heard it right. Still using XP). So without installing Win32 version of grep could this be done in a Windows batch file?

Comment: This may be possible with some arcane cmd.exe trickery. It's probably a lot easier to just copy grep.exe to the computer and use that. You can also install PowerShell 2.0 on XP.

Answer (score 1):

Just use your familiar `grep` and other great Linux commands by downloading this [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/)  (ready .exe binaries). Add it to your `PATH` environment variable for convenience